# How to set the path of installing Apache IoTDB through command?

Tags: path, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I compiled source code of IoTDB, I want to set the startup path to the path I created, but seems like I cannot find this path when I install IoTDB. Is there a way to specify the path through command in Apache IoTDB?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please